# Gradient colour with Linear Gradient Border in text using css not working

Tags: html, css, css-shapes, linear-gradients

I would like design **£1** similar to the following image using CSS.

[image: £1]

I would like to have some text with gradient colour, gradient border and text-shadow in this design. I tried the following code, but it doesn't work.

*CSS:*

```
.pound-lbl {
       background-image: linear-gradient(275deg, #f8e71c 0%, #f8bd1c 100%);
       -webkit-background-clip: text;
       color: #FFDE17;
       text-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
       background: -webkit-linear-gradient(275deg,#F8CC1C 0%, #FFFFFF 100%);
       -webkit-background-clip: text;
       -webkit-text-stroke: 2px transparent;
}
```

Comment: Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/wilsmex/pen/KHEIC) with good examples on how to achieve this

Comment: Does your problem involve no background colour being applied to the form

Comment: @MarcHjorth gradient colour or  gradient border only one of them working i have allready try this.

Comment: is this ionic 4 ? What exactly isnt working, is it just the background or is it everything ? what element are you applying this on, as it may not be applicable due to the shadow dom ? providing html would be useful

Comment: the last background declartion is erasing the first background-image and also the background-clip

Comment: try removing the background-clip, it should work

Comment: @akshaykishore i would like to have only text design given in image.
background-clip remove it set background in the label not on text.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Last background declaration is for border and first background-image is for text gradient color.

Comment: -webkit-background-clip:text  ... wouldn't that give a background only for the text..It worked why I tried it out in my local editor, so maybe give it a try?

Comment: @IraJW no it's not a ionic 4

Comment: you think it's like that but for the browser it's not .. the first one is useless

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the only way to have this effect is to duplicate the text. One will get the stroke coloration and the other the background coloration:

I used different colors to better identify them:

```css
span[data-text] {
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:90px;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-family:arial;
  position:relative;
  margin:10px;
}
span[data-text]:before {
  content:attr(data-text);
  text-shadow: 0 2px 20px purple;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,red 0%, blue 100%);
  -webkit-text-stroke: 5px transparent;    
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  color:transparent;
}
span[data-text]:after {
  content:attr(data-text);
  left:0;
  top:0;
  position:absolute;
  background-image: linear-gradient(275deg, green 0%, yellow 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<span data-text="£1"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

## Gradients on text

When you need to set gradients on text css is not the tool to use.
Its easier to use **svg** for advanced gradient and all complex shapes.

Here is how i would recomend to create the svg:

1. Define two gradient one for the background one for the text. ([LinearGradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/linearGradient))
2. Create background and text. (rect, and text, tspan)
3. Set the stroke and fill of the elements to the LinearGradients.

Here is how it would look:

```html
<!--viewBox cuts the shape so that there is little whitespace-->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="500px" height="500px" viewBox="0 40 100 60">
   <defs>
      <!--Gradients defined to use later-->
      <linearGradient id="textGradient" x1="90" x2="90" y1="40" y2="60" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
         <stop stop-color="#f2cb3c" offset="0"/>
         <stop stop-color="#ffffff" offset="1"/>
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient id="backgroundGradient" x1="0" y1="100" x2="0" y2="100" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
         <stop stop-color="#5bc129" offset="0"/>
         <stop stop-color="#85de31" offset="1"/>
      </linearGradient>
   </defs>
   <!--Rect that covers the background-->
   <rect fill="url(#backgroundGradient)" stroke="none"; width="100" height="60" x="0" y="20"/>
   <g class="text" stroke="url(#textGradient)" fill="#f5e43e" stroke-width="0.5">
      <text x="35" y="68" style="font-size:50px;font-family:Arial;">
         <tspan>£1</tspan>
      </text>
   </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: How can we add another gradient to color the text? I tried to replace the `fill="#f5e43e"` with a gradient but it's not working.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Create a new linearGradient with an ID, then you can replace the fill like this: fill="url(#ID)" where ID is the id of the gradient you want selected.

Comment: yes, nevermind. I was using bad values for x/y so I wasn't able to correctly see it.