# How to set a stroke of text with gradient border and transparent background

Tags: html, css, sass, graphics, psd

I have a `PSD` design where there is a text written with gradient stroke and transparent background.
While designing this in `CSS` I am unable to set stroke with transparent background.

I have managed it right now as white transparent and with opacity. But through this the text is less visible when this comes over the image. See [live site](https://www.jpdm.rocks/agency/) section 2 where the text is `CREATIVE`. Character 'C' & 'R' are less visible as compared to PSD.

PSD URL: https://www.photopea.com/#iybHFezVy

```css
body{background:#ccc}
.agency-banner .wrapper .col-left {
    width: 555px;
}

.heading h1, .heading h2 {
    font-size: 150px;
    line-height: 1em;
    font-family: prompt-bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    /*background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,#ed3b4b,#4c3b92 90%);*/
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(237,59,75,1) 0%, rgba(76,59,145,1) 100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 4px transparent;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: .6;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    letter-spacing: 15px;
    font-family: 'Prompt', sans-serif;
}
.agency-banner .wrapper .col-left .heading h1 {
    padding-left: 25px;
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Prompt:ital,wght@0,500;0,600;0,700;1,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="agency-banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper d-flex">
      <div class="col-left">
        <div class="heading">
          <h1>Agency</h1>
      </div>      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Doesn't seem possible with this `text-stroke` + `background-clip` approach. Have you considered using SVG?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61828996/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/q/56215721/8620333